# unix equivalent of python's os.add_dll_directory

Tags: python, unix

I found a python program on the web that plays video in a wxPython panel. I want to use it on Unix, but it has a Windows-specific call in it:

```
os.add_dll_directory(r'C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC')
```

This adds the given directory (to a list?) so that it is searched for necessary DLLs.

I know Unix has an environment variable LD_DIRECTORY_PATH that does a similar thing; I don't know whether the VLC library I'm using would use it the same way as the directory in the add_dll_directory call.

I searched the target unix system for what seemed to be the primary DLL filename to try to locate a directory that way, but did not find it. The VLC program is installed on the unix machine, and plays videos just fine, but the program using the python-vlc module fails when it is time to load the video.

Can someone help me figure out what to add to the unix program to duplicate this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The environment variable on unix is `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. You can try setting this in the Python session's environment like this:

```
import os
os.environ["LD_LIBRARY_PATH"] = "/path/to/vlc/libraries"
```

To be nice, you should probably check if it's already set and append to any existing path, separated by `:`.

Anything run under that Python session should inherit the environment and **should** find the libraries but I can't say that I've never seen this fail to work from time to time.